# Comparing class attribute to variable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

So, I am writing a Django application, and there is this little nasty bug. I have the following code:

```
def appendProduct(self, productID):
    for product in Product.objects.all():
        if product.product_id == productID:
             currentProduct = product
```

Somehow that `if` never evaluates to `True`. I don't get this. I had put some console logging before that `for`loop to check the value of `productID` and there is indeed a `Product` in `Product.objects.all()` for which those ID's are the same. It is driving me nuts, any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Product.objects.get(product_id=productID)` instead of looping through the objects.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, let me call myself stupid here. Yet still, why does that not work? The product_id field returns an int for sure, and productID is an int too.